# how to export the SMS, picture, video from iOS device programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone

I wanted to export the SMS, picture, video from non-jailbroken device using programmatically or using ideviceinstaller.

someone kindly help on this to accomplish this task

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Google photos to export the photos and videos, you can't export SMS though.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways to do it (and there are for photos and videos such as putting them on iCloud Photo Library), but if you want to access these all together, a good program you can use is [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/).

That looks to do everything you want to do.  It's not free, but I think they have a free trial you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but im not looking any tool to be used . i wanted to transfer the data from mobile to pc.

Comment: Seeker - yes and that tool will do that for you.  Short of using a tool, there is no way for you to transfer that data to your PC.

Comment: @SeekeR You'll need a "tool"